# Enumerate or map through a list with index and value in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

In dart there any equivalent to the common:

```
enumerate(List) -> Iterator((index, value) => f)
or 
List.enumerate()  -> Iterator((index, value) => f)
or 
List.map() -> Iterator((index, value) => f)
```

It seems that this is the easiest way but it still seems strange that this functionality wouldn't exist.

```
Iterable<int>.generate(list.length).forEach( (index) => {
  newList.add(list[index], index)
});
```

Comment: `Map#forEach`? is it what you want?

Comment: It's enumerating through a List not a Map

Comment: [Map#forEach](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Map/forEach.html) is enumerating through a `List`? what do you mean? the docs say: *"Applies f to each key/value pair of the map.

Calling f must not add or remove keys from the map."*

Comment: I also do not understand what you mean with "enumerate or map through a list with index and value"

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/5245 and https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32467

Answer (score 353, accepted):

There is an `asMap` method which converts the `List` to a `Map` where the keys are the indices and the values are the elements. Please take a look at the [documentation for asMap](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/asMap.html).

Example:

```dart
final sample = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
sample.asMap().forEach((index, value) => f(index, value));
```

---

If you are using Dart 3, you can alternatively use the `indexed` property. Please take a look at the [documentation for indexed](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/IterableExtensions/indexed.html).

Example:

```dart
final sample = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (final (index, item) in sample.indexed) {
  f(index, item);
}
```

Comment: Quite disappointing for a JS dev, that there's a need for "conversion" here to iterate through a list with index

Comment: map() is supposed to return a value so that that one type of list is transformed into a new list type. forEach() returns void. You might as well only use forEach().

Comment: @user2233706 `asMap` is different that `map`. `map` iterated through an `Iterable` and maps it to the return type of mapper function. `asMap` converts `Iterable` to a `Map<int,IterableTYpe>`. The forEach is applied on the Map returned by `asMap`

Comment: I get a feeling this doesn't guarantee ordering. Does it?

Comment: @sleighty It guarantees ordering.  As stated in [the `.asMap` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/asMap.html): *The `Map.keys` `Iterable` iterates the indices of this list in numerical order.*

Comment: One disadvantage of `.asMap` is that it works only on `List`s and not on arbitrary `Iterable`s.

Comment: Because `Map.map()` has the signature `map<K2, V2>(MapEntry<K2, V2> Function(K, V))`, it is impossible to convert a list to another data structure via e.g. `someList.asMap().map().toList()`.

Answer (score 204):

You can use the [`mapIndexed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/mapIndexed.html) or [`forEachIndexed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/forEachIndexed.html) extension methods from the [`collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package. Note that unlike javascript's `array.map()` or C#'s `IEnumerable.Select()`, the index is the first argument, not the second argument of the callback:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  final inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
  final indexes = inputs.mapIndexed((index, element) => index).toList();
  
  inputs.forEachIndexed((index, element) {
    print('index: $index, element: $element');
  });

  print(indexes);
}
```

#### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2e6e2ba341d08dfe0907d6ca6efebe40&null_safety=true)

---

### Old answer

Starting with Dart 2.7, you can use [`extension` methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) to extend the functionalities of `Iterable` instead of having to write helper functions:

```dart
extension ExtendedIterable<E> on Iterable<E> {
  /// Like Iterable<T>.map but the callback has index as second argument
  Iterable<T> mapIndexed<T>(T Function(E e, int i) f) {
    var i = 0;
    return map((e) => f(e, i++));
  }

  void forEachIndexed(void Function(E e, int i) f) {
    var i = 0;
    forEach((e) => f(e, i++));
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
final inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
final results = inputs
  .mapIndexed((e, i) => 'item: $e, index: $i')
  .toList()
  .join('\n');

print(results);

// item: a, index: 0
// item: b, index: 1
// item: c, index: 2
// item: d, index: 3
// item: e, index: 4
// item: f, index: 5
```

```dart
inputs.forEachIndexed((e, i) => print('item: $e, index: $i'));

// item: a, index: 0
// item: b, index: 1
// item: c, index: 2
// item: d, index: 3
// item: e, index: 4
// item: f, index: 5
```

### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/86ce74d95798635e14c8b848863b429f?null_safety=true)

Comment: this is the best answer, this even works with Flutter items where you could return Widgets not just String.

Comment: So, where you have `List<Widget>`,  T and E represent List and Widget respectively? How does the incremental line work with a return statement ie. not explicitly passing the increment via a closure. I imagined they'll all receive "1" as their index. Secondly, why doesn't `i` start at -1?

Comment: @IWantAnswers `E` and `T` represents the type of the item in the original array/output array respectively, because you can map to an array with different type. For example, if you write a function that get all names from a list of `Widget`, it'd be `widgetList.mapIndex(w => getName(w))` where `widgetList` is `List<Widget>` and  the result is `List<String>`

Comment: @IWantAnswers the increment happens every time after the callback `(e) => f(e, i++)` is evaluated. If `i` starts at `-1`, it'd need to be `++i`. e.g. the increment happens before the callback is evaluated.

Comment: I get the "generic" explanation. Naming things well always helps. It's interesting that i++ and ++i both represent different behaviour in .net. Your response on the closure is what I suspected but haven't quite come to terms with cuz I can't wrap my head around the Internals of such a parameter. How does the compiler maintain reference to "increment"? It is neither a type nor a fixed variable. So, how do the closures stored on the stack know to evaluate their argument during each iteration? Or maybe I'm just being pedantic and should go with the flow. Learning from your answers. Many thanks!

Comment: I think I get it. `(e) => f(e, i++))` is not a function signature but an expression itself. It could as well be "$i is a number".  It's a neat trick

Comment: Still disappointed for this is not builtin in dart.

Comment: @JohnWang you can use the collection package now which is developed by dart team, the best part is that it's also used by flutter so you don't have to install it, just import the package and use the `.forEachIndexed` or `.mapIndexed` variants. My answer was updated with an example for reference.

Answer (score 48):

There is no built-in function to get the iteration index.

If like me you don't like the idea to build a `Map` (the data structure) just for a simple index, what you probably want is a `map` (the function) which gives you the index. Let's call it `mapIndexed` (like in Kotlin):

```dart
children: mapIndexed(
  list,
  (index, item) => Text("event_$index")
).toList();
```

The implementation of `mapIndexed` is simple:

```
Iterable<E> mapIndexed<E, T>(
    Iterable<T> items, E Function(int index, T item) f) sync* {
  var index = 0;

  for (final item in items) {
    yield f(index, item);
    index = index + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but would probably be better written as a synchronous generator

Comment: @DavidRees thx for the suggestion! I also renamed the function `mapIndexed`

Comment: It's a shame that dart does not have a built-in easy way to do this. Even 30 years old python can do this easily!

Comment: It turns out that `.asMap().forEach()` is essentially the same as this - see my answer.

Comment: @Timmmm I think `asMap()` will cost additional loop to retrieve data, thus it will not efficient as `mapIndexed()` above.

Comment: @anticafe: It also only does one loop. Check the code in my answer.

Comment: Look at NearHuscarl's answer

Answer (score 25):

Building on @Hemanth Raj answer.

To convert it back you could do

```
List<String> _sample = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
_sample.asMap().values.toList(); 
//returns ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Or if you needed the index for a mapping function you could do this:

```
_sample
.asMap()
.map((index, str) => MapEntry(index, str + index.toString()))
.values
.toList();
// returns ['a0', 'b1', 'c2']
```

Answer (score 21):

I initially thought `['one', 'two', 'three'].asMap().forEach((index, value) { ... });` would be really inefficient because it looks like it is converting the list to a map. Actually it isn't - the documentation says it creates an immutable *view* of the list. I double checked with the `dart2js` of this code:

```
void main() {
  final foo = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  foo.asMap().forEach((idx, val) {
    print('$idx: $val');
  });
}
```

It generates *lot* of code! But the gist is this:

```
  main: function() {
    var foo = H.setRuntimeTypeInfo(["one", "two", "three"], ...);
    new H.ListMapView(foo, ...).forEach$1(0, new F.main_closure());
  },

  H.ListMapView.prototype = {
    forEach$1: function(_, f) {
      var t1, $length, t2, i;
      ...
      t1 = this._values;
      $length = t1.length;
      for (t2 = $length, i = 0; i < $length; ++i) {
        if (i >= t2)
          return H.ioore(t1, i);
        f.call$2(i, t1[i]);
        t2 = t1.length;
        if ($length !== t2)
          throw H.wrapException(P.ConcurrentModificationError$(t1));
      }
    },
    ...
  },

  F.main_closure.prototype = {
    call$2: function(idx, val) {
      ...
      H.printString("" + idx + ": " + H.S(val));
    },
    $signature: 1
  };
```

So it is smart enough to do the efficient thing! Pretty clever.

Of course you can also just use a normal for loop:

```
for (var index = 0; index < values.length; ++index) {
  final value = values[index];
```

Comment: Thanks for researching about this! I was wondering the same and because I was lazy to search, always stuck with the normal loop.

Answer (score 20):

Use **asMap** to convert List to map first. The index of element is the key. The element becomes value. Use **entries** to map the key and value to anything you want.

```
List rawList = ["a", "b", "c"];
List<String> argList = rawList.asMap().entries.map((e) => '${e.key}:${e.value}').toList();
print(argList);
```

Output:

```
[0:a, 1:b, 2:c]
```

Comment: The best answer! No extension required or any mucking around!

Answer (score 12):

**use** -> mapIndexed(index, Element) Function

to map each element and its index to a new value.

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

and use the map index as follows

```
(List).mapIndexed<Widget>(
 (mapIndex, mapElement) => Positioned(
  left: mapIndex.toDouble() * 5,
  child: Card(
   color: Colors.blue,
    child: Image.network(
     '${mapElement.ImageURL}',
      height: 80,
      width: 80))))
```

Please Refer:
https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/mapIndexed.html

Answer (score 10):

Lukas Renggli's [more](https://github.com/renggli/dart-more) package includes many useful tools including 'indexed' which does exactly what you want. From the docs:

```
indexed(['a', 'b'], offset: 1)
  .map((each) => '${each.index}: ${each.value}')
  .join(', ');
```

(You can ignore the offset argument unless you have a Smalltalk background :-).

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `mapIndexed` extension from the [collections](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  final nums = [1, 2, 3];
  final strs = nums.mapIndexed((index, element) => index.toString() + '_' + element.toString()).toList();

  print(strs); //  [0_1, 1_2, 2_3]
}
```

Comment: Importantly the collection package is shipped **inside** the Flutter SDK so is now available "out of the box" (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/package-collection_collection-library.html).

Comment: That doesn't have the extension functions, though.

Comment: yes it does: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension.html

Comment: @Maks what they meant is that you cannot import the extension methods without having to install the `collection` package. It's not in the sdk. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834536/how-to-use-lowerbound-in-flutter?rq=1#comment116403034_65834536).

Comment: @NearHuscarl I'm sorry but you are incorrect, the Flutter SDK *does* ship with the collections pkg because the SDK itself makes use of it. 
You can easily verify this by creating a new flutter project: `flutter create use_collection` then add the above code in this answer into `main.dart` & you will see collection pkg *is* available and it works without you having to add the pkg to your pubspec.

Comment: @Maks Thanks for correcting me. I never knew that before. It all makes sense now why the dartpad has the collection package and some others out of the box. This is also briefly [mentioned](https://api.flutter.dev/index.html#:~:text=can%20use%20it.-,Supporting%20Libraries,-Libraries%20in%20other) in the docs.

Answer (score 6):

For convenience you can use  this extension method.

```
extension CollectionUtil<T> on Iterable<T>  {

  Iterable<E> mapIndexed<E, T>(E Function(int index, T item) transform) sync* {
    var index = 0;

    for (final item in this) {
      yield transform(index, item as T);
      index++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Iterable.generate` factory. The following code would map an `Iterable` using indexes and values.

```
extension IterableMapIndex<T> on Iterable<T> {
  Iterable<E> mapIndexed<E>(E f(int index, T t)) {
    return Iterable.generate(this.length, (index)=>f(index, elementAt(index)));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using dart [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) you can access various list extensions

one is `mapIndexed`:

```
Iterable<R> mapIndexed<R>(R Function(int, E) convert)
```

[list of all iterable extensions](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension.html)

Comment: Importantly the collection package is shipped **inside** the Flutter SDK so is now available "out of the box" (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/package-collection_collection-library.html).

Answer (score 2):

With [records](https://dart.dev/language/records) in Dart 3, a new extension property [indexed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/IterableExtensions/indexed.html) is added to the `IterableExtensions` which can be used like this:

```
final iterable = [1,2,3,4];
for(var (index, value) in iterable.indexed) {
    print('$index => $value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`package:quiver`](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) includes an [`enumerate`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.iterables/enumerate.html) function that is similar to Python's `enumerate` function.

(Note that although `package:quiver` isn't from the Dart team, it is owned and maintained by Google, and many of its contributors are members of Google's Dart and Flutter teams.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create another variable to get index.

```
    int index = 0;

    array?.forEach((element) {
    
    // your code is here

    index++; // you should add this at end of the for loop
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution from 2023 that uses the new Dart 3 [record type](https://dart.dev/language/records).

You can use it like this:

```dart
for (final (index, item) in enumerate(items)) {
  print('$index: $item');
}
```

And this is the helper function:

```dart
Iterable<(int, T)> enumerate<T>(Iterable<T> items) sync* {
  var index = 0;
  for (final item in items) {
    yield (index, item);
    index++;
  }
}
```

It is similar to the `enumerate` function in Python.