# Get iteration index from List.map()

Tags: loops, dictionary, indexing, dart, flutter

I wrote an iteration on list of letters and put inside cards on screen using "map" class.

In the code you can see that I made a row, and using "map" printed all the userBoard on cards to the screen. I want to add some logic inside so I need to get the id of the element (for taping event).
Is there a way that I can do that?

Actually, I want to get a specific index of element over userBoard.

Code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: userBoard
                  .map((element) => Stack(children: <Widget>[
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment(0, -0.6),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (() {
                              setState(() {
                                // print("element=${element.toString()}");
                                // print("element=${userBoard[element]}");
                              });
                            }),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 40,
                              height: 60,
                              child: Card(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(element,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ]))
                  .toList(),
            )
          ],
        ),
}
```

[**Picture** - each card is "element" of the map. I want to get the indexes for the function onTap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rzap.png)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

To get access to index, you need to convert your list to a map using the [asMap](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/List/asMap.html) operator.

**Example**

```
final fruitList = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango'];
final fruitMap = fruitList.asMap(); // {0: 'apple', 1: 'orange', 2: 'mango'}

// To access 'orange' use the index 1.
final myFruit = fruitMap[1] // 'orange'

// To convert back to list
final fruitListAgain = fruitMap.values.toList();
```

**Your Code**

```
userBoard.asMap().map((i, element) => MapEntry(i, Stack(
  GestureDetector(onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      // print("element=${element.toString()}");
      // print("element=${userBoard[i].toString()}");
    });
  }),
))).values.toList();
```

**References to other answers**

- I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444027/272539) better. Please take a look.
- If you want in multiple places try extending [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60502389/272539).
- Alternatively, you could also try the [dart collection approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68357576/272539).

Comment: There's a much better approach from other answer here after dart released the collection package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68357576/8494794

Answer (score 98):

Dart has released the [`collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package that comes with a [`mapIndexed`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/mapIndexed.html) extension to all Iterables.

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  final fruitList = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango'];
  final withIndices = fruitList.mapIndexed((index, fruit) => "$index - $fruit");
  print(withIndices);
}
```

([DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=444e55bee4083e3b570af9076f2aac3f&null_safety=true))

The package comes with all sorts of handy extensions and useful tools to work with collections.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer.

I love how I always have to read the latest answers in Dart-related questions since the team keeps pushing out quality of life changes so fast.

Answer (score 88):

You can get index use `list.indexOf` when the list has no duplicate elements。

Example

```
userBoard.map((element) {
  // get index
  var index = userBoard.indexOf(element);
  return Container(

  );
}).toList()
```

Comment: It will be wrong when dublicate element in your list it returns first founded item's index.

Comment: This would be very inefficient.

Comment: dublicate elements must be checked for sure

Comment: @jamesdlin Why is it inefficient?

Comment: @SimpleUXApps Because `list.indexOf` must iterate over the list to find the specified element.  Each `list.indexOf` call is O(n), and using it for each element of the list therefore would be O(n^2).  This is inefficient since this operation could be easily done in O(n) time.

Comment: please do not do this

Answer (score 55):

### The easiest approach if you want to iterate

We can extend `Iterable` with a new function:

```dart
import 'dart:core';

extension IndexedIterable<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Iterable<T> mapIndexed<T>(T Function(E e, int i) f) {
    var i = 0;
    return map((e) => f(e, i++));
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
myList.mapIndexed((element, index) {});
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447850/1321917).

Comment: A more up-to-date solution from the linked answer: "You can use the mapIndexed or forEachIndexed extension methods from the collection package."

Answer (score 38):

Another approach using `List.generate`:

```dart
var list = ['y', 'e', 's'];
var widgets = List.generate(list.length, (i) => Text(list[i]));
```

Comment: I like this better. Lemme add a link to this in my answer.

Answer (score 14):

You can simply use the `mapIndexed` method:

```
userBoard.mapIndexed(
  (int index, element) => Container( ... ))
     .toList();
```

This is one of the many extensions from the FIC package: https://pub.dev/packages/fast_immutable_collections

---

If you don't want to add a package to your project you can just copy the extension itself:

```
extension FicListExtension<T> on List<T> {

  /// Maps each element of the list.
  /// The [map] function gets both the original [item] and its [index].
  Iterable<E> mapIndexed<E>(E Function(int index, T item) map) sync* {
    for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
      yield map(index, this[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: I'm one of the authors of that package.*

---

**Update:** I have now removed a few methods, like `Iterable.mapIndexed()` from the [FIC package](https://pub.dev/packages/fast_immutable_collections), because Google added a similar method to their [collection package](http://package:collection/collection.dart), and I want both packages to be compatible.

Answer (score 14):

You can use asMap() and entries.map() to get the index.

```dart
list.asMap().entries.map((e) {
      var index = e.key;
      var value = e.value;
      // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `list.asMap()`

```
var result = list.asMap().map((e) => '${e[0]} - ${e[1]});
print(result);
```

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/List/asMap.html

Comment: I want to send a index of "userBoard" as a parameter
userBoard.map((element) => Container(
child: Text(element)
//.... Some code and listener of button
func(element_index);

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```
children: [
          for(int index = 0; index < list.length; index++)
            Text(list[index])
        ]
```

Answer (score 3):

The current version of built-in [collection package](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/package-collection_collection-library.html) now contains the method `mapIndexed` and comprehensive set of other `List`/`Iterable` [extension methods](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension.html).

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

Answer (score 2):

### Try this:  [source](https://fireship.io/snippets/dart-how-to-get-the-index-on-array-loop-map/)

(Key in map) same (index in list)

```
myList.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
    int idx = entry.key;
    String val = entry.value;

    return something;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no build-in function to get the iteration index.

What you probably want is a `map` which gives you the index:

```dart
children: enumerate(
  list,
  (index, item) => Text("event_$index")
).toList();
```

The implementation of `enumerate` is simple:

```
Iterable<E> enumerate<E, T>(
    Iterable<T> items, E Function(int index, T item) f) {
  var index = 0;
  return items.map((item) {
    final result = f(index, item);
    index = index + 1;
    return result;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution is get hascode of your object is a unique as int
**example:**

```
yourClass.hasCode()
```

this will return a id like 123456789 for each iteration

you when use in another widgets when you need

```
onSelectChanged: (d) {
    setState(() {
       selectedRow = d == true ? object.hascode : null;
    });
 },
 selected: object.hascode == selectedRow,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`package:quiver`'s `enumerate` function](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.iterables/enumerate.html) first:

```dart
enumerate(userBoard).map((indexedValue) {
  final index = indexedValue.index;
  final element = indexedValue.value;
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform your list to another using `map`.

```dart
var yourList = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var textList = yourList.map((e) => Text(e)).toList();
```

Usage:

```dart
Column(
  children: textList,
)
```

Comment: Where is the index?

Comment: @NearHuscarl This may not directly answer what is asked in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Can also try this:

```
list.asMap().keys.toList().map((index) {
  // var item = list[index];
  // index is the index of each element.
  return youFunction(index);
});
```

I also write other approaches as well in my blog here.
https://medium.com/@channaly/map-with-index-in-dart-flutter-6e6665850ea8

Answer (score 1):

its pretty simple and straight forward in dart.

```
myList.map((item) =>
print(myList.indexOf(item));//here I printing index             
).toList()
```

Comment: This is inefficient. The default implementation iterates over the list to find the given item so you have O(n²) (if I am not completely off) for this in worst case. It's also inaccurate. Given `final myList = [0, 1, 2, 1];`, this will print `0, 1, 2, 1` instead of `0, 1, 2, 3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map map = {
'1st':'first',
'2nd':'second'}; //any data

List mapAsList = map.keys.toList(); //convert map to list to get iteration index

print( map[mapAsList[0]] ); //first 
print( map[mapAsList[1]] ); //second
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by defining a variable named index:

```js
Widget listWidget() {

  List < String > myList = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  int index = -1;

  return Column(
    children: myList.map < Widget > ((element) {
      index++;
      return Container(
        Text("$index : $element")
      );
    }).toList()
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List mapList = [{'1st':'First'},{'2nd':'Second'}];
var element=mapList.map((e)=> e.value);
int getIndex = mapList.indexof(element);
```

Comment: You should add some explanation as to how your answer solves the problem and what improvements it has compared to the numerous other answers.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34456530)