# Map a HashMap in Dart

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart

I have,
`['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'];`

I need,
`['0. apple', '1. banana', '2. carrot'];`

Right now i can do it by this way.

```
var foo = ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'];
var bar = [];
 foo.asMap().forEach((k,v){
   bar.add('$k. $v');
});
```

How can i utilize the map function to generate the similar result? Like,

`foo.map((e) => //magic line here.. ).toList();`
Trying to generate some widgets here.

Comment: You want to generate `Widget` with the usage of this list => `['apple', 'banana', 'carrot']`, or you need to have an array which looks like this = >`['0. apple', '1. banana', '2. carrot'];`?

Comment: `int i=1;
  foo.map((e){bar.add('${i++}. $e');}).toList();` This works but might not be ideal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Get iteration index from List.map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54990716/flutter-get-iteration-index-from-list-map)

Comment: hi @nvoigt, i've gone through that link before posting the issue. It's not my ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a little more, i've found the answer..

```
var foo = ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'];

var bar = foo.asMap().entries.map((i) => '${i.key}. ${i.value}').toList();

print(bar); // ['0. apple', '1. banana', '2. carrot']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to use `List`'s `.map` method here without utilizing an external counter

```dart
var foo = ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'];
int i = 0;
print(foo.map((e) => '${i++}. $e'));
```

Comment: thanks man, that's good, but i was looking for a single line approch