# How to use a Map<int, String> with the DropDownMenu Widget Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart, dropdown

I've been trying to implement a dropdown menu but i wanted to utilise the key data maps have.

a simple example of the data i want to process

```
List<String> Test = [ Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4 ];
Map<int,String> Test2 = { 0 : Test1 , 1 : Test2, 2: Test3, 3:Test4};
```

my list version:

```
  EM.DigitalFunctionList.map((String item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
     value: item,
      child: Text("$item and ${item.indexOf($item)}"),
  ),).toList(),
    ),
```

this at the moment returns a "item x and 0 " for all values so im not too sure why thats happened but

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54990716/flutter-get-iteration-index-from-list-map#:%7E:text=To%20get%20access%20to%20index,map%20using%20the%20asMap%20operator.&text=You%20can%20get%20index%20use,list%20has%20no%20duplicate%20elements%E3%80%82)

it states to get an index from a list you have to convert it to a map, so im a tad stumped

Comment: What is the value of `pattern` ?

Comment: Ah sorry that should be the item string so it looks for it. i did find an approach to getting an index by using my map but if possible id rather just use the map entirely

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this is you are trying to get the the index of item in your parent list
`EM.DigitalFunctionList.indexOf($item)`

Comment: Ahhh ok. Cheers for the reply!! il give it a wiz tomorrow and update the post !