# Is there a way to solve the problem of index inside the map?

Tags: flutter, dart

**I fetched data from `DUMMY_MEALS` and tried to extract it using the `map` and when I extracted it it works fine but when I want to use `Dismissible` I need `Index` and I don't know how to get it.**

---

## I want to solve this problem so that I can delete the item

---

**Note: I tried to use ListView.builder, but no luck**
[image]

```
Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 15,) ,
                Text('ingredients' , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25 , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                Divider(color: Colors.pink , thickness: 1,),
                ...selectMeal.ingredients
                      .map((e) => Dismissible(
                   onDismissed: (DismissDirection Dir){
                     setState(() {
                       selectMeal.ingredients.removeAt(index);
                     });
                   },
                          key: ObjectKey(e),
                          child: Card(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                              child: Text(e , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Have you try `ListView` with `shrinkWrap:true` property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop

For example:

```dart
var list = [1,2,3];

Column(
  children: [
    Text('Title'),
    for(var i = 0; i<list.length; i++)
    Text('i: ${list[i]}')
  ],
)
```

Or create a extension method on `Iterable` like suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60502389/6704033