# How to get the index of each row in a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of elements (icons), I need to get the index of rows in the list. That is, 1 row = index, I need to get this index. I can't loop through the array to get the position of each row correctly. How can I get the index of each row in the list and pass it to the _itemPicture method? I need to show the first 3 lines in purple, the remaining 4, 5 and 6 lines in green.

```
List<Widget> _convertListItems(List<dynamic> list, bool isSecondList) {
  late List<Widget> children;
   if (isSecondList) {
     children = [
      for (int i in list)
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
              child: _itemPicture(list),
            ), 
          ],
        ),
      )
      
    ];
   } 

return children;

Widget _itemPicture(List<dynamic>? list) {
     return const SizedBox(
      height: 14,
      width: 9,
      child: Icon(Icons.bolt, color: constants.Colors.purpleMain),
     );
  }
```

**list**

```
  List<int> list = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    1,
    2,
    3,
  ];
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68357576/19540575 ?

Comment: Tell me, how can I transfer the index to _itemPicture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for loop like this.

```
for (var i= 0; i < list.length; i++) Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(children: [
          for (int j = 1; j <= list.elementAt(i); j++) Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
            child: _itemPicture(list, i),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 8), Text("$i")
        ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Your _itemPicture widget may look like this.

```
Widget _itemPicture(List<dynamic>? list,int i) {
  if(i<3){
    return  SizedBox(
      height: 14,
      width: 9,
      child: Icon(Icons.bolt, color: Colors.purple),
    );
  }
     return  SizedBox(
      height: 14,
      width: 9,
      child: Icon(Icons.bolt, color: Colors.green),
    );
}
```

[image: outPut]

Comment: Tell me, if I want to show only the first 3 lines or only the 4th, 5th and 6th line, how can I do this?

Comment: For example, if I need to show not the entire list, but only purple elements or only green elements

Comment: So that at the click of a button I can alternate which colors to show and which not

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `asMap` method on your list. It will transform your List into a Map and each key will be an integer starting from `0`. Maybe it can help you.

```dart
list
  .asMap()
  .map((index, i) {
    return MapEntry(
      index,
      Padding(...)
    )
  })
  .values
  .toList()
```

Edit :
To transfer the index to _itemPicture :

```dart
Widget _itemPicture(List<dynamic>? list, int index) {
  return const SizedBox(
    height: 14,
    width: 9,
    child: Icon(Icons.bolt, color: constants.Colors.purpleMain),
  );
}
```

```dart
...
child: _itemPicture(list, index),
...
```

Comment: Tell me, how can I transfer the index to _itemPicture? –

Comment: Yes, look, I need to get the index of each row. I need to show the first 3 lines in purple, the last 4, 5, 6 lines to show in green. I can't solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you want to draw a number of icons(e.g icons.blot) that equals the index of the item list you are on (or the item itself not sure)... However, if so then just use ListView.builder when you can specify the number of widgets you wanna build and how they look: just like this:

```
ListView.builder
     itemCount: i,    //OR list[i]
     itemBuilder: (_, __) => _itemPicture(),
)
Widget _itemPicture() {
 return const SizedBox(
  height: 14,
  width: 9,
  child: Icon(Icons.bolt, color: constants.Colors.purpleMain),
 );
}
```

Maybe it needs some changes or fixes to exactly work as u want (I didn't test it)... but in general this should work

Comment: Yes, look, I need to get the index of each row. I need to show the first 3 lines in purple, the last 4, 5, 6 lines to show in green. I can't solve this problem