# Flutter iterate through List with access to index

Tags: flutter, dart, iteration

I tried some other solutions to this like using `asMap()` and `forEach` but kept getting different errors. Like it was saying the return type of my `ChartBar` isn't a 'MapEntry', as defined by anonymous closure, or `The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore cannot be used.`

```
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: myList.map((data) {
      return ChartBar(
          ///etc
    }).toList(),
  )
```

I want the `index` as well.

Comment: @mirkancal That's the question I was referring to, the solutions gave me the errors I described above.

Comment: Can you try `myList.asMap().map((MapEntry data) => data.value).toList()` ?

Comment: @mirkancal As described in the question, I get the error `ChartBar isn't a 'MapEntry'`

Comment: What is ChartBar? A widget of your own?

Comment: @mirkancal Yeah it's my own widget.

Comment: @mirkancal It doesn't make any difference, with a text widget as `Text('text')` it throws the error `The return type 'Text' isn't a 'MapEntry'` as well.

Comment: @Hasen No, your code above does not use `.asMap().map(...)`.

Comment: Also, please pay attention whom you're replying to.  You seem to be directing all of your replies to mirkancal when you're answering other people's questions.

Comment: @jamesdlin Obviously I meant that part was changed. Do you have a working example?

Comment: And again, *exact* code matters so that we can be sure that you're not making a typo somewhere.

Comment: @jamesdlin What's the exact code you want me to try? His code doesn't even include a widget.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mirkancal's suggestion didn't work because [`Map.map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Map/map.html) returns another `Map` (and therefore the enumeration callback you pass it is expected to return a `MapEntry`).

You instead need to use [`Map.entries`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Map/entries.html) so that you can use [`Iterable.map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) instead to construct a `List`:

```dart
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: myList.asMap().entries.map((MapEntry entry) {
      return ChartBar(entry.key, entry.value);
    }),
  )
```

You alternatively can use Dart's new [collection-`for` construct](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists):

```dart
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [for (MapEntry entry in myList.asMap().entries)
      ChartBar(entry.key, entry.value)
    ],
  )
```

In the above, `entry.key` will be the index, and `entry.value` will be the original value in `myList`.

Comment: With this I get the error `The type 'Map<int, String>' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable.` or `The type 'Map<int, double>' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable.` with a different List.

Comment: @Hasen Oops, I forgot to add `.entries`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: It's kind of odd code to me, why is it all contained in square brackets?

Comment: @Hasen I've updated my answer with a better explanation.

Comment: I guess it's the equivalent of the `toList()` with a map, you're constructing a List inside the square brackets.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for your help. I really like this solution.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Please see these answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447850/56974 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68357576/56974

Answer (score -1):

For the index you could use `indexOf(value)` function from the list to get index value. For example:

```
List list = List.generate(3, (int index) => index * index); // [0, 1, 4]

list.indexOf(4) // returns 2
```

As for your other issue, I'd need to see more code to see how you populate `myList`. I would suggest this approach (if it fits) to render your `Row` children. Use a function to return that list, for example:

```
buildList() {
 List<Widget> list = List<Widget>();

 chartBars.forEach((chart) => { //chartBars list with info
  // add your ChartBar widget to the list with appropiate info
  list.add(ChartBar(someProperty: chart.property));
 });
 return list;
}
```

Then on your `Row` widget just call that function when you build it's children:

```
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: buildList()      
)
```

Comment: Splitting widgets to methods is an antipattern though. https://iirokrankka.com/2018/12/11/splitting-widgets-to-methods-performance-antipattern/

Comment: Is there no simpler way to do it? There's no simple tweak to my existing code just to get the index to display?

Comment: @mirkancal thanks for the heads up, I'm relatively new to Flutter and may not be aware of best practices, @Hasen Have you tried using `myList.indexOf(data)` to show the index?

Comment: Using `indexOf()` would be rather inefficient, making what should be an O(n) operation instead O(n^2).

Comment: @mirkancal Yes `indexOf()` works but like it doesn't seem like the most eloquent way to do it.

Comment: This will not work if there are duplicate items in the list.