# How to get index number forEach iterable value in Dart (Flutter)

Tags: database, flutter, dart, foreach, iterable

I need the **index** number **forEach** iterable value because I want to update my data table. But for updating the data table I need the column ID. That's why I want the index number for each value and assign it to > i.
There are similar questions which was explained how to get the index of iterable. But in my case, I am failed to map the **CallLogEntry** and that's why I can not able to get the index of this iterable value.

```
Future callLogDB() async {
    Iterable<CallLogEntry> cLog = await CallLog.get();
    final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
    int i = 0;
    cLog.forEach((log) async {
      i++;
      // row to insert
      Map<String, dynamic> row = {
        //DatabaseHelper.columnId: 2,
        DatabaseHelper.columnName: '${log.name}',
        DatabaseHelper.columnNumber: '${log.number}',
        DatabaseHelper.columnType: '${log.callType}',
        DatabaseHelper.columnDate:
            '${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(log.timestamp)}',
        DatabaseHelper.columnDuration: '${log.duration}'
      };
      await dbHelper.insert(row);
      print('CallLog $i:: $row');
    });
    return cLog;
  }
```

Comment: I can not understand with this question. I need a solution specific to my problem.

Comment: I can not map CallLogEntry. That's why I can't get the index of iterable values.

Comment: what happens if you convert to index based `for` loop? I have added converted code in the answer below.

Comment: I tried with for loop. But unfortunately, my app was crashed.

Comment: what was the error it gave?

Comment: The error was: " your app is doing too much job " like this.

Comment: ok, doing operation in index based `for` not a good solution in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I can not map CallLogEntry.

First, you need to convert `Iterable<CallLogEntry>` into a list using `toList()` method then you can use `asMap()`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 Iterable<CallLogEntry> cLog = await CallLog.get();
 cLog.toList().asMap().forEach((cLogIndex, callLogEntry) {

      row.forEach((index, data) {

      });

    });
```

**EDIT**

```
Future callLogDB() async {
  Iterable<CallLogEntry> cLog = await CallLog.get();
  final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
  int i = 0;
  cLog.toList().asMap().forEach((cLogIndex, callLogEntry) {

    Map<String, dynamic> row = {
      //DatabaseHelper.columnId: cLogIndex,
      DatabaseHelper.columnName: '${cLogIndex.name}',
      DatabaseHelper.columnNumber: '${cLogIndex.number}',
      DatabaseHelper.columnType: '${cLogIndex.callType}',
      DatabaseHelper.columnDate:
      '${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(cLogIndex.timestamp)}',
      DatabaseHelper.columnDuration: '${cLogIndex.duration}'
    };
    await dbHelper.insert(row);

  });
  return cLog;
}
```

Comment: You helped me previously in a very easy way. I tried your solution of this post. But I'm failed. Maybe I can't implement your solution properly. Can please edit my code with your solution. Please.

Comment: You are awesome !!! It worked with slight modification. cLogIndex.nember give error because cLogIndex is the index number. I tried callLogEntry.number. And it Works!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Please see these answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447850/56974 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68357576/56974