# How to get access to all indexes in one map in Flutter

Tags: android, loops, flutter, dart

I would like to get access to all indexes in my map. Since the number of variables in the list changes.

**I tried something like this but it did not work**

```
final fruitList = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'variable', ''variable2'];
final fruitMap = myList.asMap(); // {0: 'apple', 1: 'orange', 2: 'mango'}

print(fruitMap[0-5])
```

I could imagine that you have to make a loop but I had no success in making a loop for this map. The loop should continue until every index in the map is worked through. So that you will only print[i] and output as if print[0-5] was there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enumerate or map through a list with index and value in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898767/enumerate-or-map-through-a-list-with-index-and-value-in-dart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898767/enumerate-or-map-through-a-list-with-index-and-value-in-dart) already, but the short answer is:

```
void main() {
  final list = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Mango', 'Strawberry'];
  list.asMap().forEach((index, item) => print("$index: $item"));
}
// Output:
// 0: Apple
// 1: Orange
// 2: Mango
// 3: Strawberry
```

Using `.asMap()` returns the index and item, and then you can `.forEach()` through each index-item pair.