# Error in provider flutter when i'm upload the categories: Couldn't interfer type parameter 'T'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i'm makin a ecommerce app in flutter, and when I want to do de providers it show me an error in the future builder.
Ok, the fist error was this:  type 'AsyncSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'List', and the way I solved it was adding (context, AsyncSnapshot<List>), but now a new error it appear in the futurebuilder, the code is this:

```
return FutureBuilder(
                  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                  future: Firestore.instance
                      .collection("category")
                      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                      .document("4ton5n1tQBHMnJ5jmJ4l")
                      .collection("alarmas")
                      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                      .getDocuments(),
                  builder:
                      (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Product>> alarmasSnapshot) {
                    if (alarmasSnapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
```

Any idea? the error is this: Couldn't interfer type parameter 'T'

Comment: I think you are missing the `key` mapping. Is that the only error message you are receiving?

Comment: Yes, that's the only error

Comment: Take a look at this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898767/enumerate-or-map-through-a-list-with-index-and-value-in-dart). I think you need to enumerate over your List.