# How to use lowerbound in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I see that there's a package in flutter that would let me use `binarySearch` and `lowerBound`

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/lowerBound.html

At first, `binarySearch` and `lowerBound` were undefined and using my IDE, I was told to import
`import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';`

I did and I'm now able to use `binarySearch`, but I am still not able to use `lowerBound` and there are no suggested imports for this.

The goal is to insert a value into a `List<int>` sorted by descending.

And I would like to do this.

Any ideas on why I'm not able to using `lowerBound` ?

Comment: Flutter does not provide a `lowerBound` function.  You should import [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) directly.

Comment: @jamesdlin Make an answer with this and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 2 `binarySearch()` methods in Flutter.
One in Flutter build-in package [`flutter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/binarySearch.html) and another one in third party package [`collection`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/binarySearch.html).

When you imported `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';` library, you used the first one.

According your url, you'd like to use package [`collection`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/lowerBound.html)

```
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/ ★package-collection_collection★ /lowerBound.html
```

So you should import `package:collection/collection.dart` directly.