# Retrieve data of an array

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve data of an array that stores url's and place them, each one, in an item in a list. In my example, all url's are stored in the first item. Is there a way to manipulate the field indexes todo this?
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnIF6.png][1].
Here's my code:

```
Future<void> getImages() async {
  int i = 0;
  listImgs = List(4);

  await firestoreInstance
      .collection('dados_inst')
      .where('cod_inst', isEqualTo: codInst)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    value.docs.forEach((snapshot) {
      listImgs[i++] = snapshot.get('list_view');
    });
  });
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    print(listImgs[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The `++` in here seems a mistake: `print(listImgs[i++]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to convert the `value.docs` list to a map, and use the `forEach` method of that, which gets both the index and the value:

```
value.docs.asMap().forEach((index, snapshot) {
  listImgs[index] = snapshot.get('list_view');
});
```

See also:

- [Enumerate or map through a list with index and value in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898767/enumerate-or-map-through-a-list-with-index-and-value-in-dart)